# Cheque in your name or on your name?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I need to write something like

> I will make a cheque on/in your name

What will be the appropriate preposition for the above sentence?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167394/use-of-appropriate-preposition

Comment: shall the same as given in the above link goes for making a cheque. Ain't it looking somewhat inappropriate to use 'to' for making a cheque 'to' somebody's name? Shouldn't some other preposition be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually "in" to show legal ownership. Definitely not "on." Not sure about other English speakers, but Americans tend to "make out" or "write out" a check. I'd say "I will make a check out in your name", or "I will write a check out in your name".

The use of "in" also applies to other legal documents showing benefit or ownership, for example, "The title to the car is in his name."

Comment: "Make a check on your name" is ***completely*** different!

Comment: It is different, in that no one says it in the United States; to my ear it doesn't make any sense. Checks are made "on" people's names in the UK?

Comment: Yes, but *check on* has the connotation *check up on, perform a verification of*, not *write a cheque*. Cheques are written or made out ***to***, as you say.

Comment: Ah right! Wasn't thinking about it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not make out a check "in" or "on" your name, but I would make it out **[to your order](http://ecolekoenig.com/media/Kindergartenvacationcamps1314v5.pdf)**, since a check is payable [**to the order**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=uyLP1KZVbMMC&pg=PA446&lpg=PA446&dq=%22check+payable+to+the+order%22&source=bl&ots=0ml4m7Mq2t&sig=nh0cERmHou7QlwEZGbASIZ9idhw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=tsliU_awAYqp0QXytoC4Aw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22check%20payable%20to%20the%20order%22&f=false) of someone.